# Dar Foreach em label no Chartjs / Canvas - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, canvas, chartjs

Estou com um problema aqui, que pode ser até simples, não sei
Estou usando um frame pra gráfico, onde eu posso colocar as labels que eu quero para então ela ser exibida a cada barra. Ficando assim:

[image: Cada item (Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março... corresponde a uma label no seguinte código]

Cada item (Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março... corresponde a uma label no seguinte código:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
```

Eu estou querendo trazer estas `labels` pelo banco de dados que uso, e até faço isso normalmente, e exibo o `array` normalmente. Porém, estou tentando o seguinte código:

```
var data = {
            labels: ["<?php foreach ($fase as $fase){ echo $fase->nomefase;} ?>"],
            datasets: [
```

O problema neste código, é que não consigo inserir uma vírgula para separar os itens do `array` que eu busco do banco de dados. Na hora de entrar a vírgula, o `foreach` termina, e começa novamente, fazendo com que exiba nenhum item, ou se eu tiver apenas um item no `array`, ele exibe o primeiro e só.

Tentei quebrar diversas vezes em fragmentos e tentei tanto pra fazer funcionar, porém ele dá erro.

Comment: Isso parece errado: ` foreach ($fase as $fase)` não seria algo como  foreach ($fases as $fase)`

Comment: Não não.. o foreach tá retornando tudo certinho.. eu só repeti o nome ali da variável por costume, mas poderia ser $fases as $fase que daria mesmo erro

Comment: Já tentou assim: labels: ["<?php echo implode(","  $fase); ?>"] ?

Comment: Tentei, e nao deu.. o gráfico nem aparece haha :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de criar na mão a estrutura do array javascript, deixe [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) fazer isso pra você. Só crie a lista de nomes e deixe a função imprimir o array formatado:

```
labels: <?php foreach ($fase as $f) { $labels[] = $f->nomefase; } echo json_encode( $labels );  ?>,
```

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No portal [Universidade CodeIgniter](http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br) tem um artigo mostrando o uso do ChartJS com o CodeIgniter.

http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/criando-graficos-com-chartjs-e-codeigniter/